# How to fetch the Link in JSON code using PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, hyperlink

INPUT:

echo json_encode($json_array);

**Output:**

```
{
   "subject_id": "10",
   "subjectName": "Mathematics",
   "subject_icon": "http:\/\/www.unfoldu.com\/admin\/images\/maths-icon.png"
}
```

I need a url in proper format like:

```
www.domain.com/admin/images/maths-icon.png
```

Comment: [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Comment: $classid = $_GET['classid'];
 $sub_query ="SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE subjectClass = '".$classid. "'";
 $sub_sql = mysql_query($sub_query);
 
    //create an array
    $subarray = array();
    while($row =mysql_fetch_assoc($sub_sql))
    {
        //$subarray[] = $row;
  $json_array['subject_id'] = $row['subject_id']; 
  $json_array['subjectName'] = $row['subjectName'];  
  $json_array['subject_icon'] = "domain.com/admin/images/".$row['subject_icon'];   
  
   //array_push($subarray,$json_array);  
 
    }
 
   echo json_encode($json_array);

Comment: do you need only icon name from entire URL in json?

Comment: when I decode the data than my url output like this:http:\/\/www.unfoldu.com\/admin\/images\/maths-icon.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you only need to use the JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES flag:

```
<?php 

$arr = array('subject_id'=>'10','subjectName'=>'Mathematics','subject_icon'=>'http://www.example.com/admin/images/maths-icon.png');

echo json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

?>
```

Comment: Thank u so much @Mittul At TechnoBrave